# Protobuf cannot serialize system.object

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have classes that have all the required attributes for serialization, and I'm storing them in system.object so that when the other end deserializes them, it can pattern match them and do different stuff depending on the object type.

```
object data = MyObject;
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, data, PrefixStyle.Fixed32); // exception happens here
```

Tried it with other serializing methods like XML/BinaryFormatter and it didn't seem to have a problem.

Comment: Try casting it to your type. Protobuf expects a type which can be serialized, and System.Object can't

Comment: No, I need to pattern match it when deserializing. You can do it with BinaryFormatter, so I'm not sure whether to create a base class for all of the objects to inherit

Comment: System.Object does not have the required attributes for serialization, hence your error.

Comment: Do I need to create a dummy base class for all the classes to inherit..? seems like a doable idea but ugly.

Comment: I think that might be the best way. As long as that class is serializable by protobuf, you should be fine passing your object as that type.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is very descriptive here - protobuf-net can not serialize system.object as it has not been told how to serialize/deserialize it. This is not a limitation of protobuf-net, protobuf (the spec) is a contract serialization method so it requires a specification for the type in order to serialize it.

One option is to create a base class that is marked with ProtoContract attribute and inherit from there. Be sure to include all subclasses in the base class with ProtoInclude-attribute, otherwise the serializer won't know how to serialize the subclasses.

I would advice not doing this, as serialization of subclasses is sort of add on protobuf-net provides on top of the standard protobuf behaviour, and creates problems if you need to work with other libraries and/or languages. Instead I'd advice you to create a messaging format where you encode the type separately of the object (message in protobuf terms). For example encode the type as enum as the first 4 bytes in the beginning of the message followed by the object itself. Then you can first read the type and then deserialize accordingly, without having to resort to subclasses.

Comment: Do you mean something like: Write an enum to the stream that is called for example Person, and then write the object of type Person after? Deserialize the enum, check the type, and then de-serialize the type depending on the enum result?

Comment: @Jackou Yes, exactly that. This has also the added bonus of you being able to skip deserialization of a message type that you're not interested in for a potential performance boost.